# Maven Project - can't load an image

Tags: image, maven

I'm trying to load image 'collaboration.png' in my file login.jsp:

```
<img src="img/collaboration.png">
```

However, only an error is shown instead of the image. I'm beginner in Maven - I guess a problem is in my maven structure, so I was trying to move my img directory, but I can't find correct location. Please anybody, where to move img directory for loading the image?

There is my maven project's structure:

[image]

Comment: Did my solution work?

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `jsp` and `images` are in a separate directory but you are trying to access images relatively:

```
<img src="img/collaboration.png">
```

You should instead try:

```
<img src="../../../resources/img/collaboration.png">
```

(Cross-verify once at your end, how many ../ are needed. )

You basically have to give a relative path to reach the resources/img directory. Since you are currently in `webapp/WEB-INF/view` directory, using `img/*.png` will look for the `img` directory inside view directory. 
Though you can also move your img folder inside WEB-INF and simply do `<img src="../img/collaboration.png">`, but that won't be a standard practice.